# com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: my-portal-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT not found for the web module

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, war

I have this service version in my pom.xml:

```
<artifactId>my-portal</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

After the build, I get this artifact: `my-portal-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war`

I try to deploy this artifact to local tomcat and get an error:

```
[2020-11-18 04:40:16,580] Artifact my-portal:war exploded: com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JmxAdminException: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: C:\gitProjects\my-portal\target\my-portal-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT not found for the web module.
```

Why I get this exception? And why maven/Intellij/tomcat (I don't know who) think that I have version `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`?

Comment: It is hard to tell without a project, or at least seeing project settings and pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

First, you could modify the Project Structure,and click the Artifacts,delete the origin war and war expolded,then add a new war and war expolded from your project module.
Then, modify your run server,for example,my server is tomcat, so I config this.Add the new war exploded to my tomcat deploment,and run the project again.You can have a try.

1. [The picture of Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZNwD.png)
2. [The picture of tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTDx6.png)